# C# cant understand count

Tags: c#, count

I am trying to count words in this program but i don't understand why the program  is counting for 1 number less than it must be.

For example:

> sun is hot

program will show me that there is only 2 words.

```
Console.WriteLine("enter your text here");
string text = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
int count = 0;
text = text.Trim();
for (int i = 0; i < text.Length - 1; i++)
{
    if (text[i] == 32)
    {
        if (text[i + 1] != 32)
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
}
Console.WriteLine(count);
```

Comment: You're only counting the spaces.

Comment: Have you tried debugging?

Comment: You might be interested in the `string.Split` method.

Comment: Given that this look like homework, you might want to add any conditions or restrictions that may be prevalent in the original task.

Answer (score 2):

Regular expression works the best for this.

```
 var str = "this,is:my test   string!with(difffent?.seperators";
 int count = Regex.Matches(str, @"[\w]+").Count;
```

the result is 8.
Counts all words, does not include spaces or any special characters, regardless if they repeat or not.

Comment: It's a correct solution (+1) if word is "alphanumeric characters between non-alpha numeric ones". However (just an academic remark) word in *natural languages* (English, Russian etc.) is very complex thing: "cannot" - one word, "may not" - two; "forget-me-not" - one, "do not forget me" - four etc.